# How can I make this map filter shorter & better

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I think this is not an ideal way of doing filters. I have to type more if else's and it doesn't look good.

I found a package called "useFilter". but can I just make it without using any packages? like with hooks or something.

```js
 
import { AddPosition } from "./../../data/careers/AddPosition";

const Positions = () => {
  const [positions] = useState(AddPosition);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

   <input
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
              />
             
                   {positions
            .filter((position) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return position;
              } else if (
                position.category
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return position;
              } else if (
                position.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return position;
              } else if (
                position.location
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return position;
              } else if (
                position.position
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return position;
              }
            })
            .map((position) => (
              <>
                <SinglePosition
                  id={position.id}
                  category={position.category}
                  type={position.type}
                  position={position.position}
                />
              </>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this by using `Array.prototype.some` and you can also use `useMemo` to make sure that the filtering happens only when `positions`/`searchTerm` changes.

```
const filteredPositions = useMemo(() => {
      if(!searchTerm) return positions;
      const lowerCasedSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
      return positions.filter(({id, ...other}) => {
          // assuming you want to check every value in position
          return Object.values(other).map(v => v.toLowerCase()).some(v => v.includes(lowerCasedSearchTerm))
      })
  }, [positions, searchTerm])
```

Now you can map `filteredPositions` in the JSX.

Comment: thank you! but it says "Cannot find name 'toLowerCase'."

Comment: https://prnt.sc/UXtgUuJ4KcEh still is an error. not sure why :/

Comment: @JuliaSchafer Can you add what the position object looks like? There might be some values that are not strings. What does it say when you hover on it?

Comment: yes there is an Id value with number. https://prnt.sc/hMrusAnTJSnV - https://prnt.sc/oWdwRSqSvl63

Comment: @JuliaSchafer id is causing the issue, you can separate it and rest the other props. Check the updated answer

Comment: @RameshReddy I like your solution! :) One small idea: you could move the "const lowerCasedSearchTerm = …" above the return statement, so it doesn't get recomputed every time.

Answer (score 1):

You're logic is repeated for each property of `position`. Combine them to a single array, and iterate it with `Array.some()` if any of the includes the term, it would return true:

```
{positions
  .filter(({ id, ...rest }) => {
    const term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

    return !term || Object.values(rest).some(str =>
      str.toLowerCase().includes(term)
    );
  })
  .map(position => (
    <SinglePosition key={position.id} {...position} />
  ))
}
```

Note: when rendering a list of items don't forget to include a [`key` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). In addition, you don't need to wrap a single element in a fragment. You need a fragment only if you render multiple elements without a single parent.